# New way to award bounty should be made obvious

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

[*Edit: is not a bug, it's a feature, and [a recent topic of discussion.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54444/add-popup-alert-box-to-choose-bounty-award-when-accepting-the-answer-on-bounty-qu) The new bounty system looks good, but I think for the sake of the answerers it should be made clear when you accept an answer that you've also to click on the bounty amount to award it. Now it just looks like it's giving information.*]

I accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038172) 2 days ago, well before the bounty was to expire.

Later I got an email "If you don't accept, the top-rated answer may be auto-accepted!". But the green tick was still there.

Now I just got a top-of-screen message saying it was auto-selected, and poor Kevin has only been awarded 50.

Even when I mouse-over the green tick right now, the popup says "Accepted 2 days ago".

Comment: Bounties have changed. The checkmark doesn't automatically award the bounty anymore.

Comment: WTF!? Please could we have something making that more clear? The helpful answerer shouldn't be penalized for the asker not noticing this.

Comment: @Mike it was on the blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/ (not that that is necessarily clear enough. There are several feature requests on Meta about bringing such changes to the attention of the audience more loudly.)

Comment: @Mike - In this particular case, if you want to give the answerer more rep, you could start another bounty on your own question, and then immediately award it to him.

Comment: Instead of editing a "status-completed" question to try and highlight a new problem, I'd suggest bringing this back to the original confusion and making a new suggestion for improving the visibility of the new bounty system.

Comment: @Mike Howard: Please don't alter the purpose of a post *after* it has already been answered and resolved. Besides, `status-completed` means the thread will likely receive no further attention. Start a new feature-request thread. My recommendation would be to roll this back to @Jeff Atwood's edit and start anew.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: Sorry, didn't mean to break the rules. Someone (I presume Jeff Atwood from his answer) had already edited my subject to something like "Bounty auto-select email is bugged and needs updated" which was a possible fix didn't represent my opinion, which is why I changed it to show a possible fix that did.

Comment: @Mike Howard: No rules broken, per se. It's just that the way you are going about it is confusing to others and, more importantly, will not achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops -- yes, we need to change the text of the email to reflect the new bounty rules.

I'll do that now.

Changing to:

> Don't forget to review the answers and award your bounty by clicking the bounty indicator to the left of each answer. If you don't award your bounty, the highest scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty started **may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount!**

Comment: +1 for a step in the right direction, but it would be good to have something clearer on the page itself in case the email isn't read. It's not the person not reading the email/blog who's losing out.

Comment: Can you have it pop up a suggestion to award the bounty when the user accepts an answer? Or does it already do that?