# Is the Bounty system broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

Something seems broken with the bounty system. I offered a bounty, accepted an answer prior to the deadline and then found that only half the bounty had been granted as the question had been "auto-accepted". This can't be right...

Here's the question:

[How to hint use of UIView subclass for compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254496)

Is there any way to give the answerer all he deserves?

Comment: Isn't there a warning as well, saying that accepting is not sufficient? Oh, maybe not: [Add popup alert box to choose bounty award when accepting the answer on bounty question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54444/add-popup-alert-box-to-choose-bounty-award-when-accepting-the-answer-on-bounty)

Comment: The auto-accepting of bounties is pretty ghetto too.  I've asked a question to which there wasn't a sufficient answer, so I'm left unsatisfied and without any rep points to do anything worthwhile.  Definitely won't be offering bounties any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just accept the answer - you need to click the bounty icon in order to award the full bounty amount otherwise half the bounty gets awarded (subject to some conditions.)

From the FAQ.....

> Click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer.

and

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Check out the full set of rules about bounties in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).

Comment: Hmmm. Bad design.