# My answer was accepted by the OP, but I got 50% of the bounty

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is the Bounty system broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71542/is-the-bounty-system-broken)
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I responded to a bounty that listed +200, and my answer [was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774218/algorithmic-trading-simulator-benchmark-data/5853021#5853021)

However, I only see +100 in my reputation...  This seems to be broken.  Could someone comment?

### EDIT for YOU

Did the community accept yesterday at 07:24?  The question ended today (measured on GMT)

[image: Low bounty]
[image: Accepted by OP]

Comment: This is not a bug. Accepting an answer **does not** award the bounty. Bob didn't know that and ignored the alerts saying his bounty is about to expire. Please undo your downvote on @YOU answer, as it's the correct answer..

Comment: Cheers Mike, so everything is clear now?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, yes thank you for your assistance.

Comment: some users don't know they need to click both accept button and bounty amount button. This happens before.

Comment: You'll want to upvote this feature-request: [Add popup alert box to choose bounty award when accepting the answer on bounty question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54444/155585).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OP didn't award the bounty manually, that was automatic award by Community (which is only half)

[image]

You can check it at [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5774218/revisions)

Accepts and Bounty awarding is seperate one, OP need to manually select both check mark icon and +200 box, Please take a look at [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Your answer is accepted yesterday by OP, so you got +15 yesterday, but bounty was active until today (4 hours ago from now), so half of the bounty was auto awarded today.

Comment: I think this is still a bug.  My answer was accepted by the OP.  See the update in my post

Comment: @Mike Accepting an answer and awarding a bounty are two seperate actions. This is the intended behaviour.

Comment: @Fabian, why would the community accept my answer over 24 hours before the bounty expired?

Comment: @Mike, OP accepted it, not Community. (Accepting the answer can only be done by OP)