# Why was I not given the bounty for this question?

Tags: support, bounties

I answered this question:

[WinJS getPrincipalNameAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632296/winjs-getprincipalnameasync?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I did not get the bounty for it.

Now Is there a way to understand why? 
Following those 3 point for an eligible answer:

- The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
- The answer must have a score of at least +2
- The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter

I tried to find out if there was a point I didn't satisfy, but where can I find the statistics on where and when the bounty started or ended on that specific question?

EDIT:
 I created a change request for this:

[Shouldn't an edit plus acceptance qualify for a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221795/shouldnt-an-edit-qualify-for-a-bounty)

Comment: It is not the same question as in the other is nowhere clear what happen if an edit on the answer make it so that it will be accepted

Comment: see: [Why not automatically award the bounty to an explicitly accepted answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192480/165773)

Comment: I created a change request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221795/shouldnt-an-edit-qualify-for-a-bounty

Comment: if you check the history of the question you will see that I added a comment (that was actually the answer ) and then after he told that it was the solution I just edited the old answer instead of adding a new one. Can you imagine if I had to write a new question every useful comment I add?

Comment: Better duplicate: [Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174070); this is about an accepted answer not getting the bounty awarded automatically because it was posted before the bounty was set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first answered on February 7, *before* the bounty was placed on February 10th.

As you quoted yourself:

> The answer must have been given **after the bounty was started**

Emphasis mine. You did edit the post shortly after the bounty was placed, but edits don't count here.

Unfortunately, even marking your answer as accepted during the bounty period does *not* make it eligible for automatic bounty awarding, see [Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174070)

You can see the bounty history on the [post revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21632296/revisions). This page is not linked from the question as there were no post revisions, but you can construct it yourself by taking the post id and inserting that into:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<postid>/revisions
```

Comment: I edited the question so I would not have to create a new one. mine was not a edit but ad addition. And the answer was accepted after my edit.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: Marking an answer, posted before the bounty started, as accepted doesn't count, I am afraid. I don't agree that it should work that way, but unfortunately that's how it works right now.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: See [Bounty not awarded automatically — bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174070)

Comment: The question was marked as accepted after the bounty started. This is therefore just a technicality, because the actual question was added and accepted in the right moment. It shouldn't be possible to make those kind of mistakes, it means the usability of the site is not appropriate

Comment: It is almost the same question, but mine was infact marked as answer, and during the bounty period

Comment: I know, that's what I am saying. *Marking the answer as accepted doesn't count* towards automatic awarding.

Comment: In this way it could even happen that if I answer the question 1 second before he add the bounty, (just because of the nature of the web), I will not be awarded the bounty even if the answer gets marked.And I see something like that as a bug

Comment: Indeed, that's the rules.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: I believe the bounty can still be awarded manually, if the bounty owner selects an answer specifically to receive the bounty. In this case, the bounty owner hasn't done so.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Yes, the bounty can always be awarded manually, right up to the point where it expires. But that's not at issue here.

Comment: He was not an experienced user as I am not. I didn't understand at the time that he had to do it manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I said that as the OP claimed that the automatic bounty awarding method is buggy -- if he didn't understand how bounties work, then it's understandable how one could come to such a conclusion.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: I know, it has happened to me as well. Very disappointing but nothing we can do about this now.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: The OP is claiming the automatic awarding is buggy because there was an expectation that the bounty would be awarded automatically because the answer was edited and / or accepted during the bounty period. Nowhere is it mentioned that a manual award was expected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: and the reason that he believes so is that he most likely thought that the only way a bounty was awarded was automatically.

Comment: The thing here is if you see my answer cointains two answers, and the second one is the right one. I just did not create 2 answers because it seemed silly, to have a question with only 2 answers from me. but the second part came after the bounty. Isn'nt the spirit of the bounty to help giving more interest to the questions? well it worked for me as I wouldnøt have gone back with the right answer if there was no bounty

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I don't get that impression at all; the OP here even quotes the bounty FAQ.

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: Sure, but an automated system has to follow practical rules; if the OP didn't manually award the bounty there is little we can do afterwards.

Comment: I will propose it as a change if it is still not there, because in a case like this the intentions are quite clear, the edit is what made the answer right and made it so that it could be accepted

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark but then any trivial edit could then trigger an automatic bounty.  That's not desirable either.  You are clearly upset that you didn't get the bounty.  But ultimately it is the responsibility of the owner of the bounty to award the bounty, not the system to award it out to anyone who edits their post during the bounty period.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am talking about questions accepted after the bounty started. that means the question is valid in any possible way

Comment: I mean an edit by the same user who wrote it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 if you check the history of the question you will see that I added a comment (that was actually the answer ) and then after he told that it was the solution I just edited the old answer instead of adding a new one. Can you imagine if I had to write a new question every useful comment I add?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark I get your point.  I just dislike editing being a trigger.  The issue is why accepting an answer during the bounty which was posted before the bounty was started not automatically award.  I'd like to see the argument as to why this exception is there because it doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I thought that acceptance during the bounty was enough. But is not, so I agree that it should be. But being that such an abvious and common case I thought the exception was there for a reason. That's why I took the road of the edit

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: That's why I linked to the bug report about this; see the post I linked in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I saw it but that question is not for **accepted** answers

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: I think you are looking at a different post. [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174070/bounty-not-awarded-automatically-bug) (which I linked) most definititely *is*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh yes I can see it now, but my is a support request, that is a bug. Anyway I think this question got an answer. now I think  it became a change request. :)